# Accept the transfer of a file

Tags: xcode, transactions, xmpp, xmppframework

I connect Adium client with my iphone simulator, and all is connected
and TurnSocket Succesfull
And in adium i send a file and i recive this "iq":

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="purple60d20b07"
 to="jadelmag@chatme.im/MacBook-Pro-de-Javier-Delgado"
 from="msancho@chatme.im/MacBook-Pro-de-Javier-Delgado">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</iq>
```

I guess that is a message to accept the transfer, no?

What i have to done to accept it?

Thanks

Comment: I tried the same, but I am getting user offline error on adium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zash said, it is looking to find out what extensions your client supports. Specifically, Adium is asking you for this information so it can determine if you are capable of file transfers.

This is part of the [XEP-0095 Stream Initiation](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0095.html) extension, which is used to negotiate file transfers between two clients.  After that request, a response which indicates you are capable of file transfer will lead to further negotiation as to how the transfer should occur (Socks5 bytestream or IBB typically).

Usage of [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) will eliminate the need for this step in negotiation altogether, assuming that the Adium client understands this extension.  (Thanks @Joe Hildebrand - didn't know about that extension).

Comment: Add a reference to XEP-115 (to avoid this disco#info request when possible), and you'll have a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

It wants to know what protocol extensions you support, see [XEP 30, Service Discovery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html).